# Body background color stops at the end of a child element

Tags: css, uikit

I'm trying out uikit and working with their sortable lists. The background height is being affected somehow by their grid system.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8HwI.png)

I can add elements beneath these lists, and the background stretches down, but why does this sort group make the background behave in this manner? If I remove these elements, the background fills the entire screen.

```css
body {
  background-color: #787878;
}
#main {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/css/uikit.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/css/components/sortable.almost-flat.min.css" />
<nav class="uk-navbar">
  <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
    <li class="uk-active"><a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="uk-parent"><a href="">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<br>
<br>

<div class="uk-container uk-container-center" data-uk-grid-match>
  <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-width-1-3">

    <div>

      <h3>First list</h3>

      <div class="uk-sortable uk-margin" data-uk-sortable="{group:'test'}">
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 4</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div>

      <h3>Second list</h3>

      <div class="uk-sortable uk-margin" data-uk-sortable="{group:'test'}">
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 4</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div>

      <h3>Third list</h3>

      <div class="uk-sortable uk-margin" data-uk-sortable="{group:'test'}">
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 4</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/uikit.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/core/modal.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/components/sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/components/grid.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a `min-height` and a `padding-bottom` to `body` to avoid ending straight on content end.

it might also  be wise to load `custom.css` CSS last.

```css
body {
  background-color: #787878;
  min-height: 100vh;/* fill up the screen*/
  padding-bottom:1em;/* make some space at the bottom, a bit of makeup */
  box-sizing:border-box;/* include the padding into min-height calculation */
}

#main {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/css/uikit.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/css/components/sortable.almost-flat.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css"><!-- might be wise to load custom CSS last -->
<nav class="uk-navbar">
  <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
    <li class="uk-active"><a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="uk-parent"><a href="">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<br>
<br>

<div class="uk-container uk-container-center" data-uk-grid-match>
  <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-width-1-3">

    <div>

      <h3>First list</h3>

      <div class="uk-sortable uk-margin" data-uk-sortable="{group:'test'}">
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 4</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div>

      <h3>Second list</h3>

      <div class="uk-sortable uk-margin" data-uk-sortable="{group:'test'}">
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 4</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div>

      <h3>Third list</h3>

      <div class="uk-sortable uk-margin" data-uk-sortable="{group:'test'}">
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
          <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 4</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/uikit.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/core/modal.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/components/sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/components/grid.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! Any idea why it was acting like this? In other projects the background color always fills the screen and is never affected by the elements on top of it.

Comment: @CarltonBrumbelow If that did it, you may accept this answer to make clear to everyone it is solved and can be usefull to someone else .  **You  already have a background define for HTML   
`/*! UIkit 2.27.2 | http://www.getuikit.com | (c) 2014 YOOtheme | MIT License */
html{font:400 14px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;background:#fff;color:#444}` here it is define to #fff**

Answer (score 0):

> try this, may be this will help you, you need to clear floats there

```css
body {
background-color: #787878;
min-height: 100vh;
}
#main {
    width: 75%;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/css/uikit.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/css/components/sortable.almost-flat.min.css" />



</head>

<body>

<nav class="uk-navbar">
    <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
        <li class="uk-active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li class="uk-parent"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<br><br>

<div class="uk-container uk-container-center" data-uk-grid-match>
    <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-width-1-3">

        <div>

            <h3>First list</h3>

            <div class="uk-sortable uk-margin" data-uk-sortable="{group:'test'}">
                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 4</div>
                </div>
            </div>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>

        </div>

        <div>

            <h3>Second list</h3>

            <div class="uk-sortable uk-margin" data-uk-sortable="{group:'test'}">
                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 4</div>
                </div>
            </div>

   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>

        <div>

            <h3>Third list</h3>

            <div class="uk-sortable uk-margin" data-uk-sortable="{group:'test'}">
                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">Item 4</div>
                </div>
            </div>

   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>  





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/uikit.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/core/modal.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/components/sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/components/grid.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```